# Change date variable format in R

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a dataset with a date variable:

2004/11/23
2022/8/1

So I rewrote them like this:

2004-11-23
2022-8-1

At this point class() returns "character".
I have a problem converting this to "Date".

I tried:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    # rewrite / as -
    date = gsub("/", "-", date)
  ) %>% 
  as.Date()
```

But the following error appreared:

```
Error in as.Date.default(.) : 
  do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”
```

As far as I see, my rewritten variable (2004-11-23) does not have '.'
Could anybody tell what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much about your data, I think you're going to need to do this instead:

```r
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    # rewrite / as -
    date = gsub("/", "-", date) %>% as.Date()
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be some data in `date` which do not match the expected format `%Y/%m/%d`.  You could use `grepl` to flush out such bad values:

```r
data[!grepl("^\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2]$")]
```

This is not a full solution, because how you handle anything returned by the above one-liner is up to you.  But at least this lets you identify the problematical data.